# Not able to get Text for selected webelement

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get text from class web element.
Here is my script :

```
public void test() throws InterruptedException{
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(adminUrl);
    txtUserName.sendKeys("gagnt2");
    txtPassword.sendKeys("okay123");
    btnLogin.click();
    driver.navigate().to(propertyDetails);
    System.out.println("Main Pop Up Window"+driver.getWindowHandle());

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lnkSaveAllDetails']"));
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
            "arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
    element.click();
    WebElement confirmbtn=driver.findElement(By.className("BlueBtn"));
    confirmbtn.click();


}
```

But I am getting excpetion
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Here is html format of webpage:

[image: HTML]

Comment: can you share the entire html page source please?

Comment: hae you debug your code?are you sure WebElement pop is not returning anything?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

WebElement pop= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#dvStillForSalePopup>p.para"));

Answer (score 0):

try below code...

```
    driver.navigate().to(propertyDetails);
    System.out.println("Current Window"+driver.getWindowHandle());
    Actions action= new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(btnUpdate).click().perform();
    driver.switchTo().activeElement();
    WebElement pop= driver.findElement(By.className("para"));
```